# Сохраняется локальный словарь функции

Tags: python-3.x

Пишу функцию по числам Фибоначчи, способ `Fast doubling` с запоминанием предыдущих результатов, вот код:

```
def calculate_fib(n, context={}):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    else:
        if not context.get(n // 2, 0):
            context[n // 2] = calculate_fib(n // 2, context)
        fn = context[n // 2]

        if not context.get(n // 2 + 1, 0):
            context[n // 2 + 1] = calculate_fib(n // 2 + 1, context)
        fn1 = context[n // 2 + 1]

    print(context)
    if n % 2:
        return fn**2 + fn1**2
    else:
        return fn * (2*fn1 - fn)
```

В словаре `context` сохраняются уже вычисленные значения. Если мы найдём значение 40-го числа, то напечатает:

```
>>> calculate_fib(40)
{2: 1, 1: 1}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55, 11: 89}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55, 11: 89, 20: 6765}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55, 11: 89, 20: 6765, 21: 10946}
102334155
```

Всё правильно, как и ожидалось. Но затем найдём, допустим, 13-е число. Так же вызываем `calculate_fib(13)` без передачи `context`, но видим:

```
>>> calculate_fib(13)
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55, 11: 89, 20: 6765, 21: 10946}
{2: 1, 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 5, 4: 3, 6: 8, 10: 55, 11: 89, 20: 6765, 21: 10946, 7: 13}
233
```

То есть, локальная переменная `context` сохранилась, да ещё и при втором вызове инициилизировалась не как пустой словать, а как словарь из прошлого вызова функции. Почему так происходит?

Comment: `context={}` вычисляется один раз в момент определения функции а не каждый раз при вызове.

Comment: то есть, у меня `context` является чем-то вроде атрибута функции и хранится в памяти постоянно, а не только при работе функции?

Comment: Верно. `print(calculate_fib.__defaults__)`. Конечно лучше избегать такого изменения, по сути, глобальной переменной.

Comment: Марк Лутц - "Изучаем Python", глава 17 «Области видимости и вложенные функции» и раздел «Типичные ошибки при работе с функциями» в конце.